# How do you export the content of stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, export

How can I export the content of a stored procedure using a SQL Statement?

Comment: are you exporting the code of the stored procedure or the output?

Comment: are you referring to "create" as import and "execute" as export commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by **'Content' you are talking about the code**, look into sp_helptext()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx

Here's a sample based on the old PUBS sample database

```
USE pubs;
GO
EXEC sp_helptext 'pubs.dbo.byroyalty';
GO
```

And here are the results

```
Text                                                                                      --------
CREATE PROCEDURE byroyalty @percentage int
AS
select au_id from titleauthor
where titleauthor.royaltyper = @percentage
```

BUT, if by **'Content' you mean the results**; you can either run the proc with the 'Results to File...' setting, or 'Results in Grid' and right click in the grid, and do a 'Save as...'

Answer (score 2):

[sp_helptext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx) system stored procedure might help.

```
sp_helptext YourProcedureName
```

Also I use [print](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) to see my generated sql inside a stored procedure, if you're looking for something like it :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedureName
AS
DECLARE @sql varchar(100)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable'

print @sql
--EXEC @sql
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

By the content you mean the code?

if so, you can call

```
EXEC sp_helptext proc_name
```

Note you can call it also with a view name

Answer (score 0):

You can query the "sys.sql_modules" catalog view to find the SQL source code for your stored procs and stored funcs:

```
SELECT definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('your stored proc name here')
```

Marc